# How to set response object's string params as null?

Tags: java, object, model, response

I wanna return my response object's string params are as null but I got empty strings. How can I set string params as null in my response object?

Thank you.

**MODEL:**

```
public class UserDto {

    Long id;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;

    //getter,setters
}
```

**SERVICE:**

```
{
UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
userDto.setId(null);
userDto.setFirstname(null);
userDto.setLastname(null);
return userDto;
}
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
{
    "id": null,
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
}
```

Comment: does it work if you default everything to `null` in the class declaration and only override it if using setters?

Comment: It might work. You mean I need to set these param as null in model?

Comment: That's what I meant but I'm not certain. It feels like some casting issue between Object and String.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jackson, you can create a NullStringSerializer

```
public class NullStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        g.writeNull();
    }
}
```

And add it to your ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(String.class, new NullStringSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need validation before set data to variable,
something like this in setter method

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName){
  this.firstName = (firstName == null) ? "" : firstName;
}
```

or validation in get mothod, like this

```
public String getFirstName(){
  return (this.firstName == null) ? "" : this.firstName;
}
```